# Error when trying to export Cordova app for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

We're trying to compile our Cordova application, for ad hoc distribution, but no matter how many times we re-generate the certificates or profiles, we keep experiencing this error when trying to export the app.

We had an existing native application, which we are now replacing with the updated Cordova version.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've created an ad-hoc distribution certificate specific to your profile, if you are unsure, revoke and re-create the distribution certificate, this time making sure that you select the "App Store and Ad Hoc" option when generating the certificate.